# Оставить только строки, которые содержат определенные слова

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть следующий датасет:

```
Компания    Назначение
АБ          Продажа готовой продукции
В           Оплата налогов
Г           Удаление вирусов
У           Продажа запасов
```

Нужно оставить только те строки с назначением "продажа". То есть на выходе получим :

```
Компания    Назначение
АБ          Продажа готовой продукции
У           Продажа запасов
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import re

res = df[df["Назначение"].str.contains("продажа", flags=re.I)]
```

---

результат:

```
In [6]: res
Out[6]:
  Компания                 Назначение
0       АБ  Продажа готовой продукции
3        У            Продажа запасов
```